# Usage of Collectionpager to Showing only one thing in asp.net Datalist

Tags: c#, collections, datalist

I want to show only one thing in one page.I change select page size to 1 in order to provide this But its next button does not work So I cant see other datas in DataList.

I tried something like that:

```
  <cc1:CollectionPager ID="Sayfalama" runat="server" BackNextDisplay="Buttons"
    BackNextLinkSeparator="" BackNextLocation="Split" BackNextStyle=""
    BackText="Geri" ControlCssClass="Sayfalama" ControlStyle=""
    FirstText="İlk Sayfa" HideOnSinglePage="True" IgnoreQueryString="True"
    LabelStyle="" LabelText="Sayfalar :" LastText="Son Sayfa" MaxPages="100"
    NextText="İleri" PageNumbersDisplay="Results" PageNumbersSeparator="&amp;nbsp;"
    PageNumbersStyle="" PageNumberStyle="" PageSize="1" PagingMode="PostBack"
    QueryStringKey="Sayfa"
    ResultsFormat="{2} tane makaleden {0} - {1} arası gösteriliyor"
    ResultsLocation="None" ResultsStyle="" SectionPadding="15" ShowFirstLast="True"
    ShowLabel="False" ShowPageNumbers="False" SliderSize="15" UseSlider="False">
</cc1:CollectionPager>
```

Can you help me please?What Can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem solution I have set `ShowPageNumbers="False"` but when it false it does not allow to change page with next button in order to change page first of all you should click to a number then back and next buttons work succesfully therefore `ShowPageNumbers` property must be true.